# Create 2dsphere index of polygon in subfield

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I'm having problems creating a 2dsphere index in MongoDB 3.6. I have a series of polygons in GeoJSON. One of the polygons is the following example (simplified to just 4 points):

`GeoJSON
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a92b5ad370dfa460e07f2ab"), 
    "type" : "FeatureCollection", 
    "crs" : {
        "type" : "name", 
        "properties" : {
            "name" : "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    }, 
    "features" : [
        {
            "type" : "Feature", 
            "properties" : {
                "ManCatID" : NumberInt(3075), 
                "ManCatName" : "Field1"
            }, 
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon", 
                "coordinates" : [
                    [
                        [
                            -2.590805067250554, 
                            52.57471588485983
                        ], 
                        [
                            -2.594339050478125, 
                            52.57415879313657
                        ], 
                        [
                            -2.590791776038, 
                            52.573727037479124
                        ], 
                        [
                            -2.590805067250554, 
                            52.57471588485983
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}`

When trying to create the 2dsphere index as explained in the [official website example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/), I need to use the subfield 'features.geometry.coordinates'. However, it fails when I try to create with `db.CaseStudies.createIndex({ features.geometry: "2dsphere" });`.

If I use `db.CaseStudies.createIndex({ geometry: "2dsphere" })` I obtain no error. However, when I do a query, I always obtain 'null' results. The query I'm using is:

`db.CaseStudies.findOne({ geometry: { $geoIntersects: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -2.592, 52.574 ] } } } });`

Do anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful to include the specific error message. It looks like you have a syntax error when creating the index: `features.geometry` should be quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using this query instead?:

```
db.CaseStudies.findOne({
  "features.geometry": {
     $geoIntersects: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -2.592, 52.574 ] } }
  }
});
```

The field on which you match should be `features.geometry` instead of `geometry`.

---

Concerning the failure when creating the index, can you try with quotes around `features.geometry`:

```
db.CaseStudies.createIndex({ "features.geometry": "2dsphere" });
```

Comment: Using the quotes around `features.geometry` gives no error, but using the suggested query still return null results...

Comment: Sorry forgot to change the collection name I used to test. Is it better?

Comment: Yes, I noticed and it was not working. However, I deleted the collection and added just the single point I gave as an example and it works. I think I was querying out of the shape I had stored. Thank you very much, Xavier. You solved the problem :D